# How to iterate over a list to get specific attributes only

Tags: java, arrays, collections, iterator, listiterator

I have a list

```
List<Widget> specialWidgets = WidgetUtil.getInstance().findAllWidgetsForType(WidgetType.UNIQUE);
```

which returns a list with widgets ids and names

```
[Widget [id=4f90b95d-8eb3-41e0-b3b1-d9ea516e1012, name=blue widget]
```

How do I get just the ids into a list using java 7?

Comment: Please update the question or tags to include the library you're using. (i.e. were do the Widget, WidgetUtil, and WidgetType come from?)

Comment: @Jason: I understand you are a newbie to this, but you need to be more clear with your questions. This will most probably be marked duplicate soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the list that you just received from the service, pull out ID field from each Widget object and push that information into another List object.

```
List<Guid> specialWidgetsIds = new List<Guid>();

foreach (Widget w in specialWidgets) {
    specialWidgetsIds.Add(w.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create new List and then add ids from specialWidgets to new List

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using jkd8, using lambda expression to convert

List specialWidgetIds = WidgetUtil.getInstance().findAllWidgetsForType(WidgetType.UNIQUE).stream().map(p -> p.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());

- If you are using jdk7, jdk6... 
  just do like pkamathk's suggestion.